# Joomla Fatal error

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla and i have created a component folder as com_joomlabook
within that 2 files as joomlabook.php and joomlabook.html.php

But when i run it in the browser using http://localhost/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7-Stable-Full_Package/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlabook

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ntdg/public_html/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7-Stable-Full_Package/administrator/components/com_joomlabook/joomlabook.php on line 6 that is in the getPath line why so??Please suggest me.

Comment: Maybe you can find a solution but that explanation.Take a look [Here][1] !


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496221/fatal-error-require-once-function-require-failed-opening-required-dir

Answer (score 1):

Did you "install" the component or add a row to the components table? Joomla doesn't just see what folders are there and run scripts.

I actually just wrote a blog post last week on how to create your own components quickly, which might be useful: http://infuseddesign.co.uk/blog/7-joomla/24-building-joomla-components