# Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__

Tags: php, android

I'm new to PHP and Android. I've tried to find a solution on existing threads, but no success.

I'm working on an android project in which I need to connect to external database. I've managed to create an external database using WAMP and it worked fine on a localhost.

Now I'm trying to get the external DB online and I'm using the 000webhost.com.
I've created a copy of my database via 000webhost.com services and trying to connect to the DB via my scrips and the credentials that the 000webhost.com provided me with. (DB_HOST, DB_USER and etc...)

I have a script that should display all existing users. i.e. it should connect to the DB and display in web browser all the information from the DB (I'm connecting through web to http://www.mywampserver.netau.net/android_connect/get_all_users_placedescoverer.php), but it fails with the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(__DIR__/android_connect/db_connect_placedescoverer.php)
[function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/a2056935/public_html/android_connect/get_all_users_placedescoverer.php
on line 12
```

In my get_all_users_placedescoverer.php in line 12 i have:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/android_connect/db_connect_placedescoverer.php';
```

And `db_connect_placedescoverer.php` exists in the same folder as `et_all_users_placedescoverer.php`.

I've also tried to use:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)'/android_connect/db_connect_placedescoverer.php'));
```

but then i get:

> Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: **Filename cannot be empty in** /home/a2056935/public_html/android_connect/get_all_users_placedescoverer.php on line 13

A help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The constant requires a later PHP version. The string concatenation requires a string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the PHP Version

The magic constant `__DIR__` is only available as of PHP v.5.3.0, as stated in the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

000webhost is probably using a lower version.

Create a file with the code `phpinfo();` in the webserver and check php version.

To fix the script for usage in a php bersion prior to 5.3.0, change line 12 to:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);

require_once $dir . '/android_connect/db_connect_placedescoverer.php';
```

### EDIT:

Are you sure you have the file in the right place? The file should be place inside a directory called android_connect.

Try using the relative path to your file from where you're calling the require.

If your index.php (i'm assuming index.php is the file requiring the other php file) is placed in public_html directory then try using the relative path

```
require_once 'android_connect/db_connect_placedescoverer.php';
```

If they are in the same folder then you can just use the file name:

```
require_once 'db_connect_placedescoverer.php';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, but it did not work I still get the same error:Warning: require_once(/home/a2056935/public_html/android_connect/android_connect/db_connect_placedescoverer.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a2056935/public_html/android_connect/get_all_users_placedescoverer.php on line 13

Comment: Sorry for that, IT WORKED!!! I've changed: $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

require_once $dir . '/db_config_placedescoverer.php';